# Git removing deleted files from tracking

Tags: git

I'm new to Git so please bear with me. I initialized my repository and used 'git add .'

What happens if I delete a file and commit? Do I need to reuse 'git add .'? How do I ensure that when I push to master on github, the deleted file won't be there?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'wont be there.' you can use git rm but others can still go back in the history and retrieve this file. If you committed and pushed a file with a password you'd have to rewrite your tree. There are plenty of answers on this site to tell you how to do this and the ramifications.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `git rm` to delete a file and make Git recognize the deletion.

```
git rm path/to/file
git commit
git push
```

Comment: I deleted a bunch of files from my folder that I don't want to appear when I commit and push. Is there a way to reupdate the entire repository with the current files in the directory? Because I don't remember the names to use git rm

Comment: Type `git status` and it'll show you what files are missing. You could use `git add -u` to mark all missing files as removed.